# Get the email of my PayPal customer

Tags: paypal

I need to read the email of the buyer that has completed a transaction on my eCommerce site. Paypal does send me an email of notification, but does not contain the email of the buyer (Instead, it returns just the transaction-id - which takes me to my account.)

I was looking through the PayPal for Developer API, but I can't find an example to get this level of detail. Is this even possible to retrieve, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal ipn returns the address. When you post to PayPal, they request an address by default. ([Source](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/))

`no_shipping =2` is the prompt for requiring an address.